# Sublime Text 3 (Windows 10) - Command Palette Won't Open, its mixed up with Package Manager

Tags: sublimetext3

I installed package manager and a bunch of packages right after I installed SublimeText3. When I go to Tools -> Command Palette, its opens up the package manager. Also, it said before that its key binding is `CTRL + \` but when I ran that, it did nothing. So I set a new key binding for it:
[image]

and when I run that key binding, it opens up the package manager. Thats kind of useful for me because `CTRL + SHIFT + P` does not open the package manager for me (hence why I added it to the user keymap file, it still doesn't work though). I can't actually find package manager in the key bindings file.

So somehow the command palette is tangled up with the package manager. Is there a file where all of the commands are listed and mapped? How would I go about fixing this?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the package manager I'm talking about is Package Control:
[image]

Comment: What package manager are you using? Is there some reason you're not using Package Control? I assume that's not it, since it provides no `package_manager` command nor a key binding for opening it.

Comment: Whoops sorry, I forgot to mention that. Its package control I'm using. I don't actually know the command name, I want to create a keybinding to launch `Package Controll: Install` because thats the only tool in there I really easy. But whats really bothering me is not being able to open the command pallette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/) provides its list of commands from the command palette itself, so that might be the source of your confusion. In particular:

- If you open the command palette (<kbd>Shift+Ctrl+P</kbd> by default under Windows/Linux), the package control commands can be found in it prefixed by the text "Package Control:", for example "Package Control: Install Package". Thus you can find the commands there by entering `pc:` in the command palette.
- Package Control modifies the main menu by adding a `Preferences > Package Control` menu item which, when selected, opens up the command palette pre-populated with the filter that filters down to only see package control commands.

So in answer to your question, there is a file where the various commands are listed out. Commands are added to the command palette by way of `.sublime-commands` files. If you use [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) you can use it to open up the `Default.sublime-commands` file provided by the `PackageControl` project.

This is a simple JSON file that provides the captions and associated commands that make up PackageControl's additions to the command palette. If you wanted to bind a key to invoke a PackageControl action directly, such as installing a package, you can find it's entry in the file to determine the command.

The entry in the file for the install command is:

```json
{
    "caption": "Package Control: Install Package",
    "command": "install_package"
},
```

So you could bind this to a key with something like:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+i"], "command": "install_package" }
```

If instead you wanted to bind a key to do what the `Preferences > Package Control` menu item does, opening the command palette and showing only the list of Packge Control commands, you can replicate what the menu command does by showing the overlay with the text pre-populated. To get at how that works, you can open up the `Main.sublime-menu` file provided by PackageControl (also using PackageResourceViewer) to see what command is doing that.

Such a binding would look like this:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+i"],
    "command": "show_overlay",
    "args": {"overlay": "command_palette", "text": "Package Control: "}
}
```

Note that this is the same as the default command for opening the command palette, only we are providing an extra option to specify what text the text entry field should be initially populated with.